# two grounds already wired together in outlet box

Tags: electrical

I'm trying to install a wall light to a fixture that simply had a bare bulb. In the box, the two black (ground?) are already wired together. Do I attach the ground from the new light to the two grounds already bound together so all three blacks/grounds are connected to each other?
Thanks!

Comment: BLACK IS NOT GROUND. The earthing connection is bare. Based on the question, I'd suggest hiring this one out to an electrician.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I agree with @Comintern: given your apparent knowledge, there's nothing we could suggest that might not end in disaster.

Comment: Grounds are always and only green, yellow/green or bare, unless you are doing old work in the former Soviet bloc.  I have no earthly idea where you got black for ground, but discard any other information you may have gotten from that source.

Comment: Weere in the world did you get "black is ground" from!?  Also, can you post a photo of the inside of the box?

Comment: Black is ground in low voltage circuits. Like an automotive system, red=positive(+), black=negative(-). House wiring....like said, hire this one out unless you want to do some deeper learning and understanding. NO shortcuts in 120/240 systems...they can kill you or burn down your home. YIKES!!